# How to access field values in a map in firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, snapshot

I have two apps. I'll call the first one RiderApp and the second one DriverApp. The users on the RiderApp can access a page where they can see a list of 6 different questions. The 6 questions are dropdown menus where they can check off the boxes that best fit their answer to each question and then save their answers. Each Each question is saved in Cloud Firestore as a Map and the answers are saved as fields which hold a boolean value. Fields marked as true are boxes that the user checked off and false are boxes that the user didn't check off.

This is where my issue comes into play. On the DriverApp, I have set up a page where the users can see this page that the user on the RiderApp has saved. They can see each question BUT I am having trouble tapping into this data in order for the users on the DriverApp to see which boxes were checked off by the user on the RiderApp.

I'm trying to do something on the DriverApp where I want to show a checkmark Icon next to the answers that the user on the RiderApp checked off.

I have everything pushing to the database correctly I'm just not sure how I can now access it in order to show in the DriverApp correctly.

Any help would be much appreciated! Below are some screenshots. Apologies for the red boxes. Had to cover up some sensitive information.

[image: 1. Cloud Firestore Structure]

[image: 2. Page with questions on RiderApp]

[image: Page with questions on DriverApp where I hope to show checkmarks only on the answers that the user on the RiderApp checked off]

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing, let's summarize a bit. Do you want to model a quiz in firestore, these questions and answers will be the same for all users?

Comment: @GabrielNexT You could think of this as a quiz. All questions and answers are the same for all users. However, the users on the RiderApp (Picture #2) are the only ones that can actually take the quiz. The users on the DriverApp can be looked at as the teachers and they need access to see the answers that the users from the RiderApp submitted. This is shown in picture #3; however, I only have dummy icons in there for now hence why there is a checkmark icon shown for every answer in picture #3. I need to access this data so that I can show a green checkmark icon next to RiderApp answers ONLY.

Comment: Well, you need to provide any code you were trying to read data. So people can point out where you have mistakes. If you don't know how to do it, just read documentation. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document